# Trouble with strings and files

Tags: c++, file-io, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a lab for my CS course that involves opening three files and providing output to a fourth based on the data obtained. I'm having some issues (I'm rather rusty at C++) and the code is giving me a headache. I've had errors with strings and segmentation faults

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//Necessary objects/structures
struct student {                            //create a structure to contain all data     consistent to the student
    string ID, name, address, phone;
    bool is_In_Query;
    list<string> class_Grade;               //Dynamic list to contain all letter grades since we don't know how many there will be
};

//Prototypes
bool readStudentFile(string, vector<student>);
bool readGradeFile(string, vector<student>);//returning a boolean will report if read was a success
bool readQueryFile(string, vector<student>);
void outputReportFile(string, vector<student>);
float calculateGPA(student);                //Pass all calculations and reading to functions to simplify and manage code
void reportFileError(int);                  //Reports a file error. "1" is Student, "2" is Grade, "3" is Query
int isSame(string, vector<student>);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    vector<student> studentList;            //Allow a range in number of students


    if (!readStudentFile("students.txt", studentList)){
        if (!readGradeFile("grades.txt", studentList)){
            if(!readQueryFile("query.txt", studentList))
                outputReportFile("report.txt", studentList);
            else
                reportFileError(3);
        }
        else
            reportFileError(2);
    }
    else
        reportFileError(1);

    return 0;                               //Termination

/*
    if (!readStudentFile(argv[1], studentList)){
        if (!readGradeFile(argv[2], studentList)){
            if(!readQueryFile(argv[3], studentList))
                outputReportFile(argv[4], studentList);
            else
                reportFileError(3);
        }
        else
            reportFileError(2);
    }
    else
        reportFileError(1);

    return 0;                               //Termination
*/
}


bool readStudentFile(string fileToRead, vector<student> studentInfo)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int index = 0;

    //inFile.open(fileToRead.c_str());            Original opening line
    inFile.open(fileToRead.c_str(), ifstream::in);

    if (!inFile.good())
        return false;
    else while (!inFile.eof()) {            //Read in order
        getline(inFile, studentInfo[index].ID);
        getline(inFile, studentInfo[index].name);
        getline(inFile, studentInfo[index].address);
        getline(inFile, studentInfo[index].phone);
        ++index;                            //We use a prefix to insure that index is incremented BEFORE the jump back to the else-while
    }
    inFile.close();
    return true;
}

bool readGradeFile(string fileToRead, vector<student> studentInfo)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    string temp;
    int sameID = 0;

    inFile.open(fileToRead.c_str(), ifstream::in);

    if (inFile.fail())
        return false;
    else while (!inFile.eof()) {            //Got more? Ok, let's go!
        cin.ignore();                       //The class ID is not necessary for our computation
        getline(inFile, temp);              //Obtain student ID
        sameID = isSame(temp, studentInfo); //Find it in our list of IDs
        if (sameID != -1){                  //If there is a match, get letter grade
            getline(inFile, temp);
            studentInfo[sameID].class_Grade.push_back(temp);
        }
                                            //No match? Ignored.
    }
    inFile.close();
    return true;
}

bool readQueryFile(string fileToRead, vector<student> studentInfo)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int sameID = 0;
    string temp;

    inFile.open(fileToRead.c_str(), ifstream::in);

    if (inFile.fail())
        return false;
    else while (!inFile.eof()) {
        getline(inFile, temp);
        sameID = isSame(temp, studentInfo); //We get an ID, compare it
        if (sameID != -1)                   //If it's in there, we'll flag it to not report a GPA of 0 due to a bug
            studentInfo[sameID].is_In_Query = true;
    }
    inFile.close();
    return true;
}

void outputReportFile(string fileToWrite, vector<student> studentInfo)
{
    ofstream outFile;

    outFile.open(fileToWrite.c_str(), ifstream::out);
    outFile.setf(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);

    for(int x = 0; x < studentInfo.size(); x++){
        if (studentInfo[x].is_In_Query){
            outFile << setw(12) << studentInfo[x].ID;
            outFile << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(7) << calculateGPA(studentInfo[x]);
            outFile << studentInfo[x].name;

        }
    }

    cout << "Finished.\n";
}    

float calculateGPA(student scholar)
{
    float gpa = 0;
    if (scholar.class_Grade.size() == 0)
            return 0;
    else {
        for(list<string>::iterator it = scholar.class_Grade.begin(); it != scholar.class_Grade.end(); ++it)
        {
            if(*it == "A")
                gpa += 4.0;
            else if (*it == "A-")
                gpa += 3.7;
            else if (*it == "B+")
                gpa += 3.4;
            else if (*it == "B")
                gpa += 3.0;
           else if (*it == "B-")
                gpa += 2.7;
            else if (*it == "C+")
                gpa += 2.4;
            else if (*it == "C")
                gpa += 2;
            else if (*it == "C-")
                gpa += 1.7;
            else if (*it == "D+")
                gpa += 1.4;
            else if (*it == "D")
                gpa += 1.0;
            else if (*it == "D-")
                gpa += 0.7;
            else if (*it == "E")
               gpa += 0;
        }
    }
    gpa = gpa / scholar.class_Grade.size();
    return gpa;
}

int isSame(string id, vector<student> studentInfo)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < studentInfo.size(); x++)
    {
        if (id.compare(studentInfo[x].ID) == 0)
            return x;
    }

    return -1;
}

void reportFileError(int report_num)
{
    switch(report_num){
        case 1 :
            cout << "No valid student file" << endl;
            break;
        case 2 :
           cout << "No valid grade file" << endl;
            break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "No valid query file" << endl;
            break;
    }
}
```

(I hope I put that in correctly for a code block)

If I try to use a predifined file name or one from the CLI arguments I get the same errors. I'm guessing it either has to do with the structures I made or the complexity I overdid.

All files are included in the directory with my code and executable file

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What errors are you getting? What lines? Can you narrow the code down for us?

Comment: If you could include the errors, that would be helpful.

Comment: The errors **only** say "Segmentation fault (core dumped). We're using Fedora with g++ and I have no idea how to run a debug on these things

Comment: Don't you need to pass `studentInfo` by reference into all functions?  Passing it by value ought to mean that additions to the vector fail to be reflected in calling code.  So much of the code will deal with an empty vector.

Comment: Thanks for that simonc, I misread some of the instruction. They said not to send it by reference for some reason or another and I misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `readStudentFile` writes directly into a vector that has not been resized yet.

You have to either resize before indexing it:

```
studentInfo.resize( studentInfo.size() + 1 );
student & record = studentInfo.back();
getline(inFile, record.ID);
getline(inFile, record.name);
getline(inFile, record.address);
getline(inFile, record.phone);
```

Or create a record and append it:

```
student record;
getline(inFile, record.ID);
getline(inFile, record.name);
getline(inFile, record.address);
getline(inFile, record.phone);
studentInfo.push_back(record);
```

Comment: Ok, I started using this and it seemed to clear up the "segmentation fault" error. Got past that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two problems that immediately come to mind based on your code.  First, when you create a vector such as `studentList` the default size and capacity are both 0.  When you then access the vector like `studentList[index]` you are accessing beyond the end of the vector and overwriting some random piece of memory.

If you know the max number of students (doesn't look like you do) then you can initialize the vector as `vector<student> studentList(maxNumberOfStudents)`.  That will give you a vector with maxNumberOfStudent entries where each entry contains the default constructed version of all the fields (for strings they will be empty).  Alternatively, you can use something like `studentList.push_back(student())` to append a new entry to the vector.  You can probably fine a cleaner way to do that but that is the general idea.

Second, when passing the `studentList` vector to the functions you will want to pass it by reference (`vector<student>& studentList`).  Without the `&` you are passing by value which means you are making a copy of the vector each time.  As several of the functions modify the vector, if you pass by value you will modify the copy but the original will remain unchanged.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining that! We jumped right into these data containers (maps, sets, lists, array, vectors) without explanation of use and passing to functions. I'll start modifying the code to see if any errors clear up